# how can I use MediaPlayer outside my mainActivity in android (how to call it from mainActivity)

Tags: java, android, media-player

IM trying to create a simple app and for it I have to have a mediaPlayer not in the mainActivity. how can I do this?(in what kind of class does it need to be and how to write the method and instance it in main).
Im quite new to android and have nooo idea how to do this(its probably very simple...)
any help would be great. thanks ahead!

Comment: You have to show us some sort of effort in solving the problem. StackOverflow isn't a 'code-order' website. [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)? What possible solutions do you think there are? Have you tried looking around for this answer anywhere else?

Comment: Try using a service http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Answer (score 3):

You can create such a class for usage in every Activity:

```
public class MediaPlayerUtil {
    public static void playSound(Context context, int soundFileResId) {
        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, soundFileResId);
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.reset();
                mp.release();
                mp=null;
            }
       });
       mp.start();
    }
}
```

Then inside any Activity just call `MediaPlayerUtil.playSound(this, R.raw.your_sound_file)` where this will be a reference to your activity and by R.raw.your_sound_file you reference file in /res/raw directory of your project.

Comment: first of all thanks for your answer. Secoond is it possable to specify the file name in the MediaPlayerUtil (I want to make it random from a selection)?

Comment: Yes, certainly. You can specify a list of resource ids for your sounds inside MediaPlayerUtil class and choose one randomly on every call.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a simple app like to ask just have to create the folder raw, where the audio was located.
mysong replace the file with the name of your audio

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  View.OnClickListener {
    Button play, stop;
    MediaPlayer mp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        play = (Button)findViewById(R.id. play);
        stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stop);

        play.setOnClickListener(this);
        stop.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.play:
                play();
             break;
            case R.id.stop:
                stop();
                break;
        }
    }
    private  void play (){
        destruir();
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mysong);
        mp.start();
    }
    private void stop(){
        mp.stop();
    }
    private void destruir(){
        if (mp !=null)
            mp.release();
    }
}
```